# .htaccess rule to force https to root directory and specific sub domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to force https to root directory and a specific subdomain only BUT removing www from every domain.

The following condition removes `www` from all domain and redirects all to `https`. Whereas I need `https` for only root and a subdomain `demo`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need more than one rewrite rule here:

```
# remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# if https is off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# a specific subdomain demo
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# if https is off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @anuhava Thanks for the code. But there's a small issue, it is still forcing my other subdomains `eg: test1` to https

Comment: It works without `www`. www.test1.domain.com still points to `https`

Comment: What is exact URL you entered `https://www.test1.domain.com` or `http://www.test1.domain.com`? First redirect rule in my answer will make it `test1.domain.com`, did this happen? If not then show your full .htaccess in question and provide full URL you're using for testing.

Comment: I entered `www.test1.domain.com`

Comment: It redirects to https://test1.domain.com but I need `https` force only for `root` and `demo` subdmain

Comment: Basically what is needed is : #1 Need to remove `www` from root and subdomains.  

# 2 https force root and subdomain `demo` only.

Comment: Nope that is not happening due to these rules as we have `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` lines. Clear your browser cache and try again.

Comment: As I said show your full .htaccess in question first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94423/discussion-between-anubhava-and-kunwarbir-s).

Answer (score 0):

right now looks to me your rule says something like...
If the http_host has www.
rewrite to be without www and with https.

I think you need to split the rules up to rules like.
If the http_host has www.
remove www
if request_uri is the root
add https.

I think you are close but i think you need multiple rules not just a single conditional.